# sql server merge with multiple insert when not matched

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert, identity

I'm using MERGE in my query and i'm making INSERT on clause WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN, but then i would like to get the inserted row identity and make another INSERT to some other table. Query for now is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkMergeOffers]
@data ImportDataType READONLY
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @cid int = 0
MERGE dbo.oferta AS target
USING @data AS source 
ON    (target.nr_oferty = source.nr_oferty)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (nr_oferty,rynek,typ_transakcji, typ_nieruchomosci,cena,powierzchnia, rok_budowy, wojewodztwo, miasto, dzielnica, ulica, opis, wspolrzedne, film, zrodlo, KontaktStore, data, forma_wlasnosci, stan_techniczny, liczba_pokoi, liczba_peter, pietro, material, kuchnia, pow_dzialki, typ_dzialki, woda,gaz, prad,sila, przeznaczenie,lokal_dane)
      VALUES (source.nr_oferty,source.rynek,source.typ_transakcji,  source.typ_nieruchomosci,source.cena,source.powierzchnia, source.rok_budowy, source.wojewodztwo, miasto,    source.dzielnica, source.ulica, source.opis, source.wspolrzedne, source.film, source.zrodlo, source.KontaktStore, source.data, source.forma_wlasnosci, source.stan_techniczny, source.liczba_pokoi,     source.liczba_peter, source.pietro, source.material, source.kuchnia, source.pow_dzialki, source.typ_dzialki, source.woda,source.gaz, source.prad,source.sila, source.przeznaczenie,source.lokal_dane);
```

So as you see i need to insert some values to the target table based on source data, then i need to take the insert identity and insert it into another table but also based on some source data, so something like that, just after the first insert:

```
SET @cid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
if source.photo is not null
begin
insert into dbo.photos(offerID, file) values (@cid, source.photo);
end
```

But i can't assemble it, a have no access to the source no more, also if statement show error :

> "the multi-part identifier
>   source.photo can not be bound"

but it is there. Just for clarity ImportDataType is a table-valued parameter.

Please HELP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't need the `WHEN MATCHED` part of the `MERGE` statement in your query, there's no real reason to use `MERGE`. You could use `INSERT` with an outer join or `NOT EXISTS` statement.

In either case, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to retrieve the inserted identity value an pass it on to a second query.

I've extended your example:

```
<stored procedure header - unchanged>

--declare a table variable to hold the inserted values data
DECLARE @newData TABLE
(nr_oferty int
,newid int
) -- I'm guessing the datatype for both columns

MERGE dbo.oferta AS target
USING @data AS source 
ON    (target.nr_oferty = source.nr_oferty)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (nr_oferty,rynek,typ_transakcji, typ_nieruchomosci,cena,powierzchnia, rok_budowy, wojewodztwo, miasto, dzielnica, ulica, opis, wspolrzedne, film, zrodlo, KontaktStore, data, forma_wlasnosci, stan_techniczny, liczba_pokoi, liczba_peter, pietro, material, kuchnia, pow_dzialki, typ_dzialki, woda,gaz, prad,sila, przeznaczenie,lokal_dane)
      VALUES (source.nr_oferty,source.rynek,source.typ_transakcji,  source.typ_nieruchomosci,source.cena,source.powierzchnia, source.rok_budowy, source.wojewodztwo, miasto,    source.dzielnica, source.ulica, source.opis, source.wspolrzedne, source.film, source.zrodlo, source.KontaktStore, source.data, source.forma_wlasnosci, source.stan_techniczny, source.liczba_pokoi,     source.liczba_peter, source.pietro, source.material, source.kuchnia, source.pow_dzialki, source.typ_dzialki, source.woda,source.gaz, source.prad,source.sila, source.przeznaczenie,source.lokal_dane)
OUTPUT inserted.nr_oferty, inserted.<tableId> INTO @newData; 
-- replace <tableId> with the name of the identity column in dbo.oftera

insert into dbo.photos(offerID, file)
SELECT nd.newid, pt.photo
FROM   @data AS pt
JOIN   @newData AS nd
ON     nd.nr_oferty = pt.nr_oferty
WHERE  pt.photo IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm using WHEN MATCHED also for updating, just stripped it for clarifying the sample, my bad. But your sample is interesting i will try to analyze it and adjust to my needs, it is a good reference.

Comment: I was a good advice indeed, thx, i've managed to get it work.

Comment: Note that the `MERGE` is still useful if you need to output data from the source record, too.  The `MERGE` `OUTPUT` statement can return both the inserted data and the source data, whereas the `INSERT` statement can only return values from the inserted row.